# Force-reboot a windows machine that can't be restarted normally

Tags: windows, command-line, ssd, data-recovery, reboot

The machine in question is an intel-based windows laptop with a defective SSD that works for the most part but accessing specific addresses causes it to not respond any more until the whole machine reboots.

I am trying to write an automated tool to recover it's data, and as part of that tool, in case a read operation does not respond within a set time, I want it to force-reboot the machine and then continue from where it stopped + single sector.

I have tried to force-reboot with the following command:

```
shutdown -r -t 0 -f
```

But it just stuck at Windows "Restarting ..." screen. I have to use the physical button to make it actually reboot.
So I'm searching for a way, whether it be a command line tool or a Win32 API, to hard-reboot automatically without the need of using the physical button.

Comment: Is it stuck in the bios or while booting Wwindows ?  Is it stuck if you reboot via Windows command?

Comment: It stuck in Windows, while it is still shutting down.

Comment: Try adding in `/p` `Turns off the local computer only (not a remote computer)—with no time-out period or warning.` Doesn't say if it will still reboot or just shutdown.

Comment: Might also be worth checking that you have [write cache turned off](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-disk-write-caching-external-storage-windows-10). I'm just guessing here but Windows might be trying to write the cache to the disk on shutdown but of course, it can't and hangs forever.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I tried them both but the original problem persists.

Comment: Windows taking a long time to shutdown is a strong indicator that files on the system disk are on sectors of the disk with a problem. The command you’re using is the command to use. There isn’t another command to shutdown the system

Comment: Windows does not offer a way to uncleanly reboot.

Comment: If it is not shutting down then its likely that either there is an error on the paging file or there is less storage for it than installed ram.

Comment: Highly recommend that you pull the drive to a different computer to perform the data copy/recovery, and not try to continue using the system the disk is running on.

Answer (score 1):

*Before* you try to recover data, **make a disk image** as best you can, **without booting from that drive**. Each time it reboots, the machine inevitably writes more to the SSD, causing additional damage.

There are many tools to make bootable rescue imaging media, such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree/) and [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/).

Using *Reflect*, for example,

- [Create rescue media](https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW7/Creating+rescue+media), perhaps on a USB flash drive of 8 GB or larger.
- Get an external disk drive at least as large as the SSD.
- On the afflicted PC, boot to BIOS and enable boot from USB.
- Reboot, using the USB made above, possibly selecting boot device (depending on BIOS).
- Insert the external drive USB cable (you can unplug the flash drive if need be after booting).
- Refresh the list of drives shown in *Reflect*.
- ["Set Macrium Reflect to ignore bad sectors when creating an image"](https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW/Imaging+disks+with+bad+sectors) and make a full drive image. This hopefully will proceed without interruption.
- **Recover your files from this image**, not from the original SSD causing issues

Comment: This will hit the error OP describes: Reading certain logical addresses will freeze the SSD entirely.

Comment: @DanielB, is it the SSD or the OS that is freezing? *Perhaps* setting Macrium Reflect to ignore bad sectors when creating an image will bypass that issue -- or not. Worth a try.